# Spring boot actuator healthcheck (AbstractHealthIndicator) response with indented JSON

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I am Spring Boot Actuator **/health** endpoints to monitor an application but the results is always like that:

```
"{ "summary" : { "results" : [ ], "duration" : 0, "executionSummaryText" : "Up and running", "failResults" : [ ] }, "applicationID" : "858", "subApplicationID" : "85822", "applicationName" : "app", "subApplicationName" : "app_reg", "applicationVersion" : null, "applicationBuildDate" : "2019-02-28 16:14:09", "applicationBuildLevel" : "5.2.0-SNAPSHOT", "timestamp" : "2019-02-28 17:16:15", "Host" : "host", "workloadStatus" : "Up and running", "detectionTime" : 3, "isaliveStatus" : "ENABLED" }"
```

but I want it to look like that:

```
    "{ 
    "summary":
    {
        "results":[],
        "duration":0,
        "executionSummaryText":"Up and running",
        "failResults":[]
    },
        "applicationID":"858",
        "subApplicationID":"85822",
        "applicationName":"app",
        "subApplicationName":"app_reg",
        "applicationVersion":null,
        "applicationBuildDate":"2019-02-28 13:19:35",
        "applicationBuildLevel":"5.2.0-SNAPSHOT",
        "timestamp":"2019-02-28 14:21:33",
        "Host":"host",
        "workloadStatus":"Up and running",
        "detectionTime":4,
        "isaliveStatus":"ENABLED"
     }"
```

I tried all of the following but it did not work:

```
http.mappers.jsonPrettyPrint=true

spring.jackson.serialization.indent_output=true

objectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
```

but none of them worked. Is there a configuration to make it work for JSON output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable [`INDENT_OUTPUT` serialization feature](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki/Serialization-features) using properties available in the [Appendix A](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html). Assuming you have not created the `ObjectMapper` bean yourself as per [this guide](https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring#with-spring-boot) the Spring Boot property is:

```
spring.jackson.serialization.indent_output=true
```

Do note this is a global change affect all endpoints which are returning JSON by serializing objects with Jackson.

Comment: Thanks a lot Karol :)